# Read XLS to import in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xls, xlsx

I am creating a module that users can upload a '.xls' file and then it must be inserted in MySQL with PHP.Server is free bsd and have all permissions by now.I have tried PHPexcelReader,but it is not working.Can u suggest me something that it can do the work.
p.s.: with phpexcelreader is writing 'The filename xxxxxxx it not readable', but it IS readable and can be downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

The filename is not readable? Is it possible the file was renamed and you are still using the old name?

Well I use PHPExcel and it's available at this link
[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: PHPExcel is about 17mb...can u tell me which classes i need only for reading the file?

Comment: Go through the docs, there are examples for you to follow. You'll know which to use.

Comment: If you don't need to write PDF files, then you can delete /Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/PDF which will reduce the overall size by a significant amount... or download the latest develop branch from https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel which has removed the tcPDF library

Answer (score 0):

You might need to pass the full absolute path to the XLS file, something like this for example:

```
/var/www/testing.somesite.com/uploads/xxxxxxx.xls
```

Or just CWD to the directory which contains the file before trying to access it.